# How to prevent Jinja2 substitution in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I goal is to replace all the `{{` and `}}` with `{% raw %}{{` and `}}{% endraw %}` in all my markdown notes so that my hexo plugin won't attempt to template when rendering.

My code is:

```
- name: Get file list of post files
  find:
    paths: "{{ hexo_data_post_file_dir }}"
  register: hexo_data_post_file_list

- name: Replace special char
  replace:
    path: "{{ item[0]['path'] }}"
    regexp: "{{ item[1]['pattern'] }}"
    replace: "{{ item[1]['string'] }}"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ hexo_data_post_file_list['files'] }}"
    - - pattern: "{{  '{{' }}"
        string: "{{ '{% raw %}{{' }}"
      - pattern: "{{ '}}' }}"
        string: "{{ '}}{% endraw %}' }}"
```

Despite I used `"{{ '{{' }}"` to ask jinja not to render `{{`, I still get error:

```
TASK [setup_docker_hexo : Replace special char] ********************************************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 27 December 2022  11:58:56 +0800 (0:00:00.491)       0:00:13.572 ******
fatal: [uranus-debian]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected 'end of template'. String: {{. unexpected 'end of template'"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the file

```yaml
shell> cat test.txt.j2
{{ test_var }}
```

---

Declare the strings [*unsafe*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_advanced_syntax.html#unsafe-or-raw-strings) to block templating. For example,

```yaml
  my_files:
    - "{{ playbook_dir }}/test.txt.j2"

  my_regex:
    - pattern: !unsafe '{{ '
      string: !unsafe '{% raw %}{{ {% endraw %}'
    - pattern: !unsafe ' }}'
      string: !unsafe '{% raw %} }}{% endraw %}'
```

Test the expansion

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ my_files }}"
        - "{{ my_regex }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['/export/scratch/tmp7/test-117/test.txt.j2', {'pattern': '{{ ', 'string': '{% raw %}{{ {% endraw %}'}]) => 
  msg:
  - /export/scratch/tmp7/test-117/test.txt.j2
  - pattern: '{{ '
    string: '{% raw %}{{ {% endraw %}'
ok: [localhost] => (item=['/export/scratch/tmp7/test-117/test.txt.j2', {'pattern': ' }}', 'string': '{% raw %} }}{% endraw %}'}]) => 
  msg:
  - /export/scratch/tmp7/test-117/test.txt.j2
  - pattern: ' }}'
    string: '{% raw %} }}{% endraw %}'
```

---

Replace the patterns

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: "{{ item.0 }}"
        regexp: "{{ item.1.pattern }}"
        replace: "{{ item.1.string }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ my_files }}"
        - "{{ my_regex }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('file', my_files.0) }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('template', my_files.0) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: '{% raw %}{{ {% endraw %}test_var{% raw %} }}{% endraw %}'

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    {{ test_var }}
```

---

Declare the variable

```yaml
  my_file: "{{ playbook_dir }}/test.txt"
  test_var: foo bar
```

and use the template

```yaml
    - template:
        src: "{{ my_files.0 }}"
        dest: "{{ my_file }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('file', my_file) }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('template', my_file) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: '{{ test_var }}'

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    foo bar
```

---

Notes

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    my_files:
      - "{{ playbook_dir }}/test.txt.j2"

    my_regex:
      - pattern: !unsafe '{{'
        string: !unsafe '{% raw %}{{{% endraw %}'
      - pattern: !unsafe '}}'
        string: !unsafe '{% raw %}}}{% endraw %}'

    my_file: "{{ playbook_dir }}/test.txt"
    test_var: foo bar

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ my_files }}"
        - "{{ my_regex }}"

    - replace:
        path: "{{ item.0 }}"
        regexp: "{{ item.1.pattern }}"
        replace: "{{ item.1.string }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ my_files }}"
        - "{{ my_regex }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('file', my_files.0) }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('template', my_files.0) }}"

    - template:
        src: "{{ my_files.0 }}"
        dest: "{{ my_file }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('file', my_file) }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('template', my_file) }}"
```

- **The playbook is not idempotent!**